# How to create an auto-updating javascript template?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a web application based on data using javascript. This data is stored as a js object and is constantly being updated using AJAX. The object has some methods to reorganize the data, such as sorting and filtering, as well as a method called `render()` which uses js templating to update the html to represent the data.

What I want is that every time the data object changes it automatically calls the render method to update the view. I know this can be done by just calling `render()` inside all my methods that modify the data, but I am looking for a cleaner way to do it.

I have read something about the observer pattern however I am not familiar with it and I don't know if I can use that to achieve this. Also I know about the Object.watch() method but that is not supported by all browsers so I can't use it.

Do you have any suggestions or examples about how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often, the flow is something like this:

1. Call Ajax;
2. On success return from the Ajax call, change the data;
3. Then call render( ) once to render everything;
4. Goto 1 after some interval or on some condition.

That gives you one render ( ) call for each Ajax update, which is likely what you want.

HTH

Comment: Thanks this works fine when updating the data, but not when sorting or filtering which do not require any AJAX calls. I am looking for a solution that would work for those cases too. Any ideas?